# Recreating a linear fit plot using R as could be plotted in Excel

Tags: r

I am not able to correctly recreate a linear fit plot in R as I could do in Excel. What am I doing wrong?

```
x <- data.frame(concn = c(0.25, 0.125, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000),
            signal = c(0.0442, 0.0343, 0.0761, 0.144, 0.201, 0.579, 1.29, 2.09, 5.25, 10.9, 24, 55.6, 112))
fit = lm(x$concn ~ x$signal)
plot(x, pch = 16, type = "p", col = "blue" ) 
abline(fit)
```

[image: R Plot][image: Excel Plot]

Comment: `plot(x$concn ~ x$signal, pch = 16, type = "p", col = "blue" ) `

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Something is wrong, your data has a y of value 1000, while the excel plot only goes to a value of 100. This might be why the coefficients are different.

Comment: x <- data.frame(concn = c(0.25, 0.125, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000),
                signal = c(0.0442, 0.0343, 0.0761, 0.144, 0.201, 0.579, 1.29, 2.09, 5.25, 10.9, 24, 55.6, 112)) is my data that I used in both instances. However the coefficients are drastically different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your order of y and x is incorrect, signal is your y, concn is your x, so it's

```
fit = lm(x$signal ~ x$concn)
plot(x$signal ~ x$concn, pch = 16, type = "p", col = "blue" ) 
abline(fit)

> fit

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      x$concn  
    0.05372      0.11198
```